# Elasticsearch output plugin in Logstash doesn't insert a document after deleting it previously

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

My app communicates with logstash, sending it objects. One of the options is upserting a document, and the other is deleting a document.
When doing one thing at the time it works perfect.
However, when I delete a document and then a couple of ms later I upsert the same document, the document is just deleted, as opposed to what should happen: the document should be deleted, and then inserted back on.

Notice that if I wait about 1 sec or so between the delete and upsert, it works fine.

This is the logs from Logstash (elasticsearch is set to debug)

```
[2022-06-09T18:25:04,535][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][a9f569aea4eb379a8e7975c049f3a3af91b5aa5f0a331341c59ef8732f0f881e] Sending final bulk request for batch. {:action_count=>1, :payload_size=>534, :content_length=>534, :batch_offset=>0}
[2022-06-09T18:25:04,581][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][d79b88d9d994ca71ad54b53446220613444ec138dc5edde62e6eaab5691bb002] Sending final bulk request for batch. {:action_count=>1, :payload_size=>119, :content_length=>119, :batch_offset=>0}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 0):

By default, logstash does not preserve the order of events. The setting pipeline.ordered can be used to control this. If there are multiple worker threads then this can also lead to events being re-ordered, so you will need pipeline.workers set to 1. Note that you have two events, a 534 byte event followed by a 119 byte event. It seems likely to me, that since both will contain the _id, the first one is the upsert of the document and contains the body of the document, and the second one is the delete, which just has the id. That suggests that your events were sent to elasticsearch in a different order that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the order - logstash does send the upsert first and then delete. I made sure that I don't mess up the order. I sent the messages to rabbitmq in the correct order, and made sure it's the order I wanted. I just started Logstash with cmd options: 1 worker, ordered true. It did not solve the problem. I also have "stdout" in the output, and in there it seems the order is fine, but again on elasticsearch log it's the opposite. Any idea how to proceed from here?

Comment: I turned on logstash logs to debug. It processes the messages by the correct order. but elasticsearch is sending the opposite order

Comment: I wonder if the output is opening multiple connections to the same instance. netstat should tell you that. Reducing max_pool_per_route might help.